# Ajax call in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, php-5.4

I am new to magento, and i am trying to make a simple ajax call in it

```
jQuery.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type : 'post',
      data: data,
      async: true,
      success: function(data){
            //alert(data.status + ": " + data.message);
            if(data.status == 'SUCCESS'){
                jQuery('.loadingOverlay').hide();
                location.reload();
            }
      }
});
```

after response i need to reload the page to see the changes done by ajax call.
Are there any other ways and how to implement them.
Can anyone help.

Comment: What errors are you getting in this code ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using jQuery... you can do that of course, but you have to make sure jQuery is properly implemented. Magento 1 uses Prototype by default, which means an Ajax Call might look about like this:

```
new Ajax.Request(url, {
        parameters: params,
        onSuccess: function(transport) {
            try {
                console.log(transport.responseText);

            } catch(e) {
                alert(e.message);
            }
        }.bind(this)
    });
```